# SWRevealViewController - How can I make the menu disappear with a tap and/or swipe on FrontViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I am developing a locator map. How can I make the menu disappear with a tap and/or swipe on FrontViewController. My front view controller displays a Map (Google Map).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable the use of swipe gestures to close your menu in the `SWRevealViewController` by adding its pan gesture recognizer to your view in `viewDidLoad:` of your view controller.

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()                 
    view.addGestureRecognizer(myRevealViewController.panGestureRecognizer())
}
```

Getting the menu to respond to taps requires handling the tap action separately with a tap gesture recognizer.

For example, with a tap gesture recognizer defined and added to your view like

```
myTapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "closeMenu")
view.addGestureRecognizer(myTapGestureRecognizer)
```

You could close the menu with a function using:

```
func closeMenu()
{      
    myRevealViewController?.setFrontViewPosition(FrontViewPosition.Left, animated: true)
}
```

where the `.Left` for `FrontViewPosition` is dependent on how you have your view controllers configured for your `SWRevealViewController`.